# How do I resolve an Azure DevOps release pipeline error to an on-prem server?

Tags: azure, iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have Azure DevOps pipeline that releases an ASP.NET Website to our on-prem IIS Test server (a pre-existing site with SSL configured for HTTPS).  The first release via the pipeline worked great (again this is a pre-existing site on the server).  However the second release resulted in the following error in the pipeline:

```
2023-05-23T21:56:54.7909604Z ##[section]Starting: IIS Web App Manage
2023-05-23T21:56:54.8033782Z ==============================================================================
2023-05-23T21:56:54.8033922Z Task         : IIS web app manage
2023-05-23T21:56:54.8033986Z Description  : Create or update websites, web apps, virtual directories, or application pools
2023-05-23T21:56:54.8034096Z Version      : 0.198.0
2023-05-23T21:56:54.8034150Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-05-23T21:56:54.8034237Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-management-on-machine-group
2023-05-23T21:56:54.8034360Z ==============================================================================
2023-05-23T21:56:56.0971058Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list site /name:"BOMViewer"
2023-05-23T21:56:56.2062650Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set site /site.name:"BOMViewer" -[path='/'].[path='/'].physicalPath:"E:\Websites\BOMViewer" -[path='/'].[path='/'].userName: -[path='/'].[path='/'].password:
2023-05-23T21:56:56.2907496Z SITE object "BOMViewer" changed
2023-05-23T21:56:56.3187374Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list sites
2023-05-23T21:56:56.4403830Z ##[command]"netsh" http show sslcert hostnameport=bomviewertest:443
2023-05-23T21:56:57.0815024Z ##[command]"netsh" http add sslcert hostnameport=bomviewertest:443 certhash=*** appid={####################################} certstorename=MY
2023-05-23T21:56:57.1364061Z 
2023-05-23T21:56:57.1367929Z SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 183
2023-05-23T21:56:57.1368575Z Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
2023-05-23T21:56:57.1376145Z 
2023-05-23T21:56:57.1376801Z 
2023-05-23T21:56:57.3438881Z ##[error]Process 'netsh' exited with code '1'.
2023-05-23T21:56:57.3679136Z ##[section]Finishing: IIS Web App Manage
```

Per my understanding, the deployment should just link to the existing SSL certificate via the thumbprint.

This same setup works fine deploying to our Dev on-prem server.  The main difference between the two builds appears to be this line:

```
 ##[command]"netsh" http add sslcert hostnameport=bomviewertest:443
```

This command doesn't exist in the logs of the Dev Release pipeline.

How can I remove the 'add sslcert' command from my pipeline?

Thanks,
Ben